# How to write a useReducer dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Link to the repo: https://github.com/charles7771/ugly-code

At the 'Options' component, I am not writing anything dynamically for a form I'm creating, I am giving each one of the reducer cases a different name. That is not scalable at all and I have no idea how to go about fixing it. Any thoughts?
It is something like this:

```
case 'SET_SMALLPRICE0':  //goes from 0 to over 20
        return {
          ...state,
          smallPrice0: action.payload,
        }
      case 'SET_MEDIUMPRICE0':
        return {
          ...state,
          mediumPrice0: action.payload,
        }
```

Comment: __I am giving each one of the reducer cases a different name.__ maybe that's the issue. try moving the price id to a field inside your Redux action.

Answer (score 0):

You could name the action type the exact name of the property to update, or perhaps with a "set_" in front. That would allow you to automatically set that property.

```
const reducerPriceCarSizeEachService = (state, action) => {
    return { ...state, [action.type]: action.payload }
}
```

or, with a "set_" in front (this could allow you to use different prefixes, such as "push_", "delete_" depending on what you actually want to do)

```
const reducerPriceCarSizeEachService = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type.startsWith('set_')) {
        let prop = action.substr(4)
        return { ...state, [props]: action.payload }
    }
    return state
}
```